# Not able to connect to mysql from other docker connector running on same machine

Tags: mysql, docker

This is my docker-compose.yml file for my ubuntu 18.04 system

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
      - ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000
      - ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT=2
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092
      - 9094:9094
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      # setup :9092 for access inside the docker network, 9094 for outside (ie host)
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka:9094
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS=10

  connect:
    network_mode: host
    image:  logan/kafk-connect:part1
    depends_on:
       - kafka
    ports:
       - "8083:8083"
    environment:
          CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: localhost:9094
          CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
          CONNECT_GROUP_ID: quickstart-avro
          CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
          CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
          CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
          CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
          CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
          CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: quickstart-avro-config
          CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: quickstart-avro-offsets
          CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: quickstart-avro-status
          CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1 
          CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1 
          CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://localhost:8081
          CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://localhost:8081
          CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG 
          CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
          CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars/tmp/quickstart/file:/tmp/quickstart/tmp/quickstart/jars:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
     

  mysql:
    network_mode: host
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: alphabeta

  landoopui:
    image: landoop/kafka-connect-ui
    links:
    - connect
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    environment: 
        CONNECT_URL: http://localhost:8083/
```

I am running mysql on docker machine .I am able to successfully connect to mysql from remote application ,but I dont know why I am not able to connect to the mysql from my `connect` container. Although I am able to connect to mysql from remote app and able to connect my connect container from other remote mysql.

I have tried these url `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kafkastudent?user=root&password=alphabeta",`

```
"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/kafkastudent?user=root&password=alphabeta",

"jdbc:mysql://serverip:3306/kafkastudent?user=root&password=alphabeta",
```

But it always gives an error communication link failure.

Similar question-https://serverfault.com/questions/914991/cant-access-mysql-database-in-docker-container-from-another-container?newreg=77b396cf0ad4480d80e2552282d11743

Comment: you should use `mysql` as DB host instead of localhost or `host.docker.internal:3306` if you are on mac or window.

Comment: I am on ubuntu...

Comment: okay, grab the system IP using `hostname -I` probably the first IP will be the host IP, use that  and it should work

Comment: nopes that not worked

Comment: A similar question https://serverfault.com/questions/914991/cant-access-mysql-database-in-docker-container-from-another-container?newreg=77b396cf0ad4480d80e2552282d11743